# Call ActionResult of Another View from form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, forms, view, controller, actionresult

I am trying to create a search form in my MVC application in View 1. The form was working very well when I used to submit the form to same page (View1). That way I can have two ActionResults - one of which accepts HttpPost requests. Everything is cool here

Now things have become slighly complex and I wish to separate the views. So in View1 there is a form and I wanted the results to be displayed in View2. So how do I call ActionResult of View2 from a form in View1?

In short - User enters keyword in View1. Hits Enter. Form in View 1 calls View2. ActionResults in View2 calls some logic to search and return View2 as the view and then I can display the results.

I tried some basic things like action="/View2" but I was pretty sure it would fail. It says 'the resource cannot be found'. Is it even possible to do this? Kindly advice.

****UPDATE****

It can be solved as answered below.

use Html.BeginForm(Name of the ActionResult,Name of the controller)

Comment: They're called _actions_, not ActionResults.

Comment: You should learn ASP.Net MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the URL of the other action in the form, preferably by calling the `Html.Form("ActionName", "ControllerName")` helper.

Comment: Wonderful thanks! I looked at some of the other questions of similar type but I was just getting stuck and some of the answers seemed too complicated for a small thing like this!